# How to test and create a test cases for angularjs in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, angularjs, testing

Developing a project in maven but and used angular JavaScript as my client side scripting.

Want to test my JavaScript in eclipse but i am not able to figure it out how to test angular in eclipse.

I tried with karma but didn't succeeded. Is there any documentation or tutorial regarding how to test and create test cases for JavaScript in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Have you by chance checked out this link? http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/02/creating-eclipse-ui-to-run-angularjs.html

Hopefully it solves what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes @Alex Thanks for it. i have to setup according to it.

Comment: Just for your information, AngularJS Eclipse 0.8.0 provides a support for Jasmine https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Jasmine-support and will provides soon a support for protractor